# Can you use RSpec Matchers independently of Rspec Expectations?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm interested in using RSpec and not throwing exceptions. I would rather get true or false. Do I just not use `should` or `expect`? Is this an officially supported use case of RSpec matchers?

To clarify, I am used to writing lines of RSpec like

```
expect(actual).to be_within(5).of(expected)
```

Can I use RSpec matchers like `be_within` and just get `false` if the condition is not met?

I don't want to have to eat exceptions with`begin` `rescue`.

I just want the matcher part of RSpec, not the exception if something doesn't match.

Comment: I do not understand your question

Comment: What do you mean, "configure to not throw exceptions"? What is your code? What are your tests? What are you trying to achieve? What errors/unexpected behaviour are you seeing? Please describe your question fully.

Comment: So, you want your tests not to fail when their expectations are not met? This doesn't make sense.

Comment: The idea is that the test records the discrepancy in an error log if the expectation is not met and moves on to checking more things.

Comment: Maybe you need something like [`aggregate_failures: true`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/expectation-framework-integration/aggregating-failures)?

Comment: If something doesn't match it does not raise an `Exception` it uses a `FailedExampleNotification` If you are experiencing `Exceptions` you should not be swallowing those but rather resolving them either by fixing the code to not raise an exception or handling the exceptions gracefully. None of this should be done in the specs themselves

Comment: Rspec expectations return `true` or `false`, and your spec will succeed or fail based on a `true/false` result. Don't believe me? Just type `true` at the end of your spec. (Then undo, and complete your valid spec).

Comment: I updated the title to make it clear again that I want to use RSpec Matchers but I'm not wanting to use RSpec Expectations. I like the matchers. I want to make it clear that I'm not using this for specs. I'm using it for an application that logs a lot of information and provides information like whether things are within certain tolerances or not. I was considering not using RSpec at all because it just does logging, but I really like the DSL RSpec Matchers provides.

Comment: This is an interesting exercise. I should give it a try when I have some down time :)